# Is it possible to group XML content by date with AMPscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, xml

I want to group the XML content with AMPscript by days. To show headlines in this order:

14 May

- Headline 1
- Headline 2

15 May

- Headline 3
- Headline 4

16 May

- Headline 5
- Headline 6
- Headline 7

The XML sample:

```
<root>
  <node>
    <title>Headline 1</title>
    <date>14 May</date>
  </node>
  <node>
    <title>Headline 2</title>
    <date>14 May</date>
  </node>
  <node>
    <title>Headline 3</title>
    <date>15 May</date>
  </node>
  <node>
    <title>Headline 4</title>
    <date>15 May</date>
  </node>
  <node>
    <title>Headline 5</title>
    <date>16 May</date>
  </node>
  <node>
    <title>Headline 6</title>
    <date>16 May</date>
  </node>
  <node>
    <title>Headline 7</title>
    <date>16 May</date>
  </node>
</root>
```

Is it possible to group headlines by dates with AMPscript?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Data Extension with two columns(Headline, Date).

You can then write an Ampscript code to lookup to this DE on date column and display the Headline. It would be something like this:

```
 %%[ SET @headlines 
 set @headlines = LookupRows('Your_DE_Name','Date',14May) 
 if rowcount(@headlines) != 0
 then   Set @row = Row(@headlines, 1)  
 Set @headlineName = FIELD(@row,"Headline") 
 endif ]%%

 %%=v(headlineName)=%%
```

If you want to make it more dynamic, you can use for loop and get data one by one. But this is how you can display headlines date-wise.
Hope it helps!

Comment: The OP is building the row from an xml not reading from a data extension